# Reloading files from disk in frame with emacsclient

Tags: buffers, frames, emacsclient, find-file

This may be user error, but if I open a file with

```
emacsclient -c file.tex
```

then if I try to reload the file using `C-x C-v`, then I get the usual

```
Find alternate file:
```

but if I press enter on that, I get

```
Buffer: `file.tex` still has clients: kill it? (yes or no)
```

If I say `yes` to that, the frame exits. If I say 'no', then nothing happens.

This seems to happen when the same file is open in multiple frames, using emacsclient everywhere. So presumably the same process is being used for these multiple frames.

Can someone explain what is going on here? What is the meaning of the message, and why does the frame exit instead of updating the file buffer in that frame?

Comment: There is something wrong in what you describe. What is your understanding of 'reload file'?

Comment: @Nsukami_ if the file has changed on disk, then reload the current version into the buffer. was the terminology I used incorrect? What should I have said instead?

Comment: Ok, you are not using the right key for that. `C-x C-v` is the key for `find-alternate-file` funtion. `revert-buffer` is the function you need

Comment: Well, `C-x C-v` normally works. I'm just wondering why it is not working here.

Comment: Normally? Can we know to which function the key `C-x C-v` is bound? And what's happening when using the `revert-buffer` function?

Comment: @Nsukami_ Whatever the default is - I haven't changed it. What should I do to discover that?

Comment: M-x revert-buffer works in this context. I tried it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19780/discussion-between-nsukami-and-faheem-mitha).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially, `find-alternate-file` kills the current buffer and immediately opens another file (creating a new buffer in its stead). Normally, this is fine. When the buffer is killed, Emacs switches to the last most recent buffer, and then immediately switches to the new buffer.

In `emacsclient`, things work differently. If you kill all buffers created *by that editing session* (e.g. by answering `yes` in your example) then `emacsclient` deems that you are done with whatever editing you were doing and kills the frame. If you say `no` than `find-alternate-file` cannot continue (it failed to kill the buffer it's trying to replace) and halts.

I'm pretty sure this is a bug, and should be fixed.

---

*However* you still really should be using `revert-buffer` if you possibly can.